# How to plot several lines with points using the plot function in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to plot a graph using the simple `plot()` function. So, I wrote this code:

```
d=read.csv("Nutrition assay example") 
head(d) 
plot(d$Carbs0~d$EAAs0, typ="p", pch=19, ylab="Carbohydrate (g/bee)", xlab="Amino acids (g/bee)") ) lines(d$Carbs0~d$EAAs0) 
lines(d$Carbs1~d$EAAs1, col="red") 
points(d$Carbs1~d$EAAs1, col="red", pch=19)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  :    invalid type (NULL) for variable 'd$Carbs1'
```

Any help and suggestions?

Comment: The error is seems to be related to your data.  They to give a minimal example with this problem.

Comment: It was working in the university computer but when I tried it on my laptop it is not working!

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without providing some sample data.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the extra parenthesis in your code.

Change this `(g/bee)") ) lines`

To this code `(g/bee)") lines`

Complete Code

```
d=read.csv("Nutrition assay example") 
head(d) 
plot(d$Carbs0~d$EAAs0, typ="p", pch=19, ylab="Carbohydrate (g/bee)", xlab="Amino acids (g/bee)")
lines(d$Carbs0~d$EAAs0)
lines(d$Carbs1~d$EAAs1, col="red")
points(d$Carbs1~d$EAAs1, col="red", pch=19)
```